# How to use XSL:Key to get the following-sibling in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, richtext

I have XML with embedded rich text formatting, which looks roughly like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <document>
     <richtext>
         <pardef/>
         <par><run>This is the </run><run>preamble.</run></par>
         <pardef list='bullet'/>
         <par><run>This is the </run><run>first bullet.</run></par>
         <par><run>This is the second </run><run>bullet.</run></par>
      </richtext>
 </document>
```

I am attempting to generate the following HTML:

```
 <p>This is the preamble.</p>
 <ul>
    <li>This is the first bullet</li>
    <li>This is the second bullet</li>
 <ul>
```

I tried the following XSL but it's not working. I have a feeling that I need to use FOLLOWING-SIBLING but I'm not sure how.

```
    <xsl:choose>

        <xsl:when test="document/richtext/pardef[@list] ='bullet'">
            <ul>
                <xsl:for-each select="document/richtext/par/run">
                    <li>
                        <xsl:for-each select="run">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </li>
                </xsl:for-each>   

            </ul>
        </xsl:when>           

        <xsl:otherwise>
            <p>
                <xsl:for-each select="document/richtext/par">
                    <p>
                        <xsl:for-each select="run">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </p>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </p>
        </xsl:otherwise>    

    </xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach with XSLT 2.0 and your "design":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:key name="key-for-par" match="document/richtext/par" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::pardef[1])"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document/richtext/pardef" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pardef[@list = 'bullet']">
        <ul>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('key-for-par', generate-id(.))">
                <li>
                    <xsl:value-of select="run" separator=""/>
                </li>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pardef[not(@list)]">
        <p>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('key-for-par', generate-id(.))">
                <p>
                    <xsl:value-of select="run" separator=""/>
                </p>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT 1:** improved version.

Comment: That worked! Although I'm actually using XSLT 2.0, which I should have mentioned earlier. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Yes it does. Have a look at **Edit 1** There are still more ways to a solution.

Comment: Thanks again! Can you clarify why the grouping is necessary? I have created XSLT stylesheets with grouping in the past, but I'd have to do some rework in order to put grouping into this one.

Comment: The axis "following-sibling" or "preceding-sibling" is not enough, cause for example element `<par>.. this is the second` is still a following-sibling of the first `pardef`. We have to stop when a new `pardef` occurs. The key in my solution group on that technic. There would be a true xslt 2.0 function `xsl:for-each-group` as well. Many ways to go :)